# Applications of word tzipor

Tags: hebrew, parashat-bereishit, birds

Can the Hebrew word "tzipor" mean any kind of flying creature in Genesis 1, or is the word only referring to fowls such as sparrows, hawks, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Scott. What other flying creatures would you think it refers to?

Comment: According to [Rav Hirsch, by way of @Isaac Moses](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7707/3), it refers to feathery things.

Comment: I was told by one man it could refer to all manner of flying creatures such as insects that fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genesis 1 doesn't use 'tzipor', it uses 'ohf' -- "flying thing."

Professor Gerald Schroeder reads this as including insects. My impression is that many centrist Orthodox rabbis, such as Rabbi Hershel Schachter, are okay with Schroeder's reading of Genesis Chapter 1, at least as a possibility.

Leviticus Ch. 11 lists the 'ohf', flying things, that are not kosher, and it includes bats.

I think 'tzipor' may actually be only "bird" birds, but I'd have to track it down with a concordance. But the word isn't in Genesis Ch. 1.

Comment: Thanks for you're help. And I stand corrected. It is the word 'ohf'.